# How to control what span takes precedence when both have overflowing content?

Tags: css, css-float, overflow

I have a structure like the following:

```
<li class="parent">
    <span class="float-left less-important">Overflowing content...</span>
    <span class="float-right more-important">More Overflowing content...</span>
</li>
```

Both of the `<span>` elements have the possibility of having overflowing content.  However, I want the second `<span>` to take precedence and expand when its content overflows, thereby shrinking the first span (the first span will use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to handle the overflow).  If the second `<span>` has minimal content, I want to expand the first `<span>` up to a certain width.

Is this something that can be done with straight CSS so that the second `<span>` will continue to expand and the first `<span>` will shrink up to a certain point?  I'm guessing this can be done through the a usage of min/max width properties.  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a way to force the first `<span>` to shrink.  Instead what is happening is the second span is going to the next line.  Also, both of these spans are set to `float` (I have no control over this).

Comment: try to use flexbox and play around `flex-basis` parameter. Read here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-background

Comment: How is it possible that you have control over a stylesheet, but no control over a `float` property??